# Running two AC-DC converts in Parallel

Tags: power-supply

First I must say that I am a basic electronic hobbies. I had typed into Google search, Running two AC-DC converters in parallel, that is how I found this site, and sign up.

As I said I am running in parallel two 300W AC-DC converters AC 220V 230V to DC 24V 12.5-15A (peak current) power switching Transformer.(that have over load, over current, & short circuit, & temperature protection).
which is wired to a 24V DC speed controller which is connected to a 24 volt DC 350 watt electric motor (brushed).

In my lack of knowledge I thought that there would be know problems doing this. But when running this set up, under load, I was taking temperature reading of the various components, just to make sure everything was o.k. When I noted that the heats sinks were a lot warmer on one of the two circuit boards. So figured there was some sort of imbalance. As I said I am a basic electronic hobbies, Is there an off the shelf solution that I could buy, and wire in?

Comment: You are correct, problem is that power supplies cannot be paralleled, unless they have specific support for it, and if they do, they would have some communication wire between them. And asking for what to buy is off topic. Why not just use a single power supply that is large enough to power the load?

Answer (score 0):

Each power supply separately tries to keep its output voltage at 24V. But each one has a slightly different reference voltage due to manufacturing variation - maybe one is 24.01V and the other is 23.99V. Good enough for most uses, except that when you connect two in parallel, the one that's trying to maintain 24.01V thinks the voltage is too low and increases its current, while the one that's trying to maintain 23.99V thinks the voltage is too high and decreases its current, so the former ends up doing all the work.

**The off-the-shelf solution is a single power supply big enough for the current you want.**

Yes, there are also some really specialized power supplies that can talk to each other and share load evenly when in parallel, but you don't need that.

The hack-job solution is to put some resistance in series with each power supply's output which gives them some slack to output not quite equal voltages. The more resistance, the better the sharing, but the more resistance, which wastes power and creates voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

> *When I noted that the heats sinks were a lot warmer on one of the two
> circuit boards. So figured there was some sort of imbalance.*

The power supply that naturally produces a slightly lower output voltage would, when connected in parallel with a power supply producing a slightly higher voltage, provide **NO** current to the load until the load current was sufficiently high that the combined output voltage dropped to the lower voltage limit.